# What does 'mkdir ../../$something/$something_else' mean?

Tags: bash

I have just read some code which includes the line:

```
mkdir ../../$something/$something_else
```

I do not know how to interpret this.

Comment: There is most probably a variable called "something", which will be used in the creating a directory with that same name using the "mkdir" command from a location that is two levels up from the current location where the code is to be run. When the code runs the  "$something" will be replaced with the actually value of that variable and the target location "$something_else" will have the suffix "_else" added to the name in the creation process

Comment: If 'something' has several values, does it create several directories?

Comment: Whatever that "$something" is set to before the "mkdir" command is called will be what the directory will be named.

Comment: I guess that the "variables" `$something` and `$something_else` just refer to some values you have to put in there suiting your special case. They are not real variables, but rather placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be understood as a convention that is used to refer to something that is written without giving the actual words, because it's thought that they are boring or unimportant. Because *$something_else* is a placeholder like *blah blah blah* `mkdir -p ../../$something/$something_else` creates a directory that has whatever name that you replace *$something_else* with. If the variable *$something_else* has been set to *myDirectory* (which is a string), then `mkdir -p ../../$something/$something_else` creates a new directory named *myDirectory*.

Comment: Does this create a directory for the values of something and something_else?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of explaining what this does is showing what it does.

Consider these shell commands:

```
$ echo $PWD
/home/rick/askubuntu/subdir-A/JSON
```

`echo $PWD` above displays our current directory.

```
$ cd ../../; echo $PWD
/home/rick/askubuntu
```

Above we've changed to our grand-parent directory and displayed it's name. Now lets change back to our original directory and display it's name:

```
$ cd /home/rick/askubuntu/subdir-A/JSON

$ echo $PWD
/home/rick/askubuntu/subdir-A/JSON
```

Now that you see what `../../` does let's tie it all together:

```
$ something=subdir-A
$ something_else=JSON2
$ mkdir ../../"$something"/"$something_else"
$ ls ../
JSON  JSON2
```

Because `something=subdir-A` is the same as our current parent directory, these two lines are equivalent:

```
$ mkdir ../../"$something"/"$something_else"
$ mkdir ../"$something_else"
```

What if `something=subdir-C` which is a brand new parent directory? Then the command we used would fail:

```
$ mkdir ../../"$something"/"$something_else"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘../../subdir-C/JSON2’: No such file or directory
```

We would need to use `-p` argument to tell `mkdir` to create missing parent directory:

```
$ something=subdir-C
$ something_else=JSON2
$ mkdir -p ../../"$something"/"$something_else"
$ ls ../../subdir-C
JSON2
```